# Ordering predicate is unsatisfiable

Tags: alloy, formal-methods

There seems to be something I don't understand about the first branch of the ordering predicate in `ff_next` of this alloy model.

```
open util/ordering[Exposure]
open util/ordering[Tile]
open util/ordering[Point]

sig Exposure {}

sig Tile {}

sig Point {
    ex: one Exposure,
    tl: one Tile
} fact {
    // Uncommenting the line below makes the model unsatisfiable
    // Point.ex = Exposure  
    Point.tl = Tile
}

pred ff_next[p, p': Point] {
    (p.tl = last) => (p'.ex = next[p.ex] and p'.tl = first)
    else (p'.ex = p.ex and p'.tl = next[p.tl])
}

fact ff_ordering {
    first.ex = first
    first.tl = first
    all p: Point - last | ff_next[p, next[p]]
}

run {}
```

The intuition here is that I have a number of exposures, each of which I want to perform at a number of tile positions.  Think doing panorama images and then stitching them together, but doing this multiple times with different camera settings.

With the noted line commented out the first instance I get is this:

[image: One pass over the panorama]

This is equivalent to one pass over the panorama with exposure one, and then dropping the other exposures on the floor.

The issue seems to be the first branch after the `=>` in `ff_next` but I don't understand what's wrong.  That branch is never satisfied, which would move to the next exposure and the start of the panorama.  If I uncomment the line `Point.ex = Exposure` the model becomes unsatisfiable, because it requires that branch.

Any help on why that branch is not satisfiable?

Comment: One code-quality trick: you can write predicates in "receiver" syntax: instead of `next[p.tl]`, you can write `p.tl.next`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually prefer the function syntax :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to express "every tile must correspond to point with the current exposure before we move to the next exposure." The problem is a major pitfall with `ordering`: It forces the signature to be exact. If you write

```
run {} for 6 but 3 Tile, 2 Exposure
```

Then that works as expected. There are only models when `#Point = #Exposure * #Tile`. You can write your own reduced version of `ordering` if this is an issue for you.

Comment: Ah!  I had suspected something like this, but was only increasing the scope for Point so it was greater than necessary!

I believe what you are saying, stated more generally, is this: If a model requires an isomorphism between two sets (Point and Expression X Tile in this case) but the scope settings do not exactly match |S1| = |S2| (|Point| = |Expression X Tile|) then the model will always be unsatisfiable?  So there's no way for a scope to be set as "but 0 to 20 Point" as needed?

Comment: I believe what I would need to do to make this model useful then, is to define a relation between Point and Expression X Tile such that some Points can be "dangling".  And then set the scope for Point such that there are always enough.  I suppose really, I need to do the same for Exposure and Tile.  Otherwise, I'm only testing a single case, up to isomorphism.  So I effectively need to invent an "arena allocator" for these three signatures?  Assuming I want one model to analyze multiple combinations of Tile and Exposure cardinalities.